# How do I configure a DCHP reservation for an IP Resource in a Windows 2008 R2 failover cluster?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, windows-cluster, failovercluster

## Background

My company has recently instituted a corporate policy that all servers are to have IP addresses that are issued via DHCP reservations to simplify the management of our IP scopes.  We have a Windows 2008 R2 Failover Cluster that is comprised of two servers to host our ERP system. I have changed the physical NICs on these servers to pull from DCHP reservations.

## Issue

In the properties screen of the IP Address resource for my clustered service, which happens to be SQL, I can change the "IP Address" setting from *Static IP Address* to *DHCP Enabled*; however, there is no option to configure a MAC address.

## Question

How do I configure an IP Address resource to take on specific MAC address so that a DHCP reservation can be created?  If this cannot be accomplished, then is there another way to get a DHCP reservation in place?

## Considerations

A new scope can be created for those devices/services that do not support retrieving their IP from DHCP, but this will likely not be available for a couple of months.

Comment: "instituted a corporate policy that all servers are to have IP addresses that are issued via DHCP" - For $DEITY sake, why?! If DHCP goes down, so do all your servers. Not to mention the potential problems of misconfigured DHCP, rogue DHCPd servers, or other problems I can't think of right now.

Comment: Sure a lot riding on DHCP working properly.

Comment: Change that policy - there's no good reason to run servers via DHCP - for exactly the reasons ChrisS gave and more - basically it's really a single point of failure and NOBODY with any experience would think of doing it if they cared for their infrastructure {cue lots of people with a few years experience defending their stupid idea}

Comment: @chris s If dhcp goes down your servers do not go down.  (unless your lease time is some ridiculously short time period).  IMO the biggest issue is the maintainability nightmare this creates.

Comment: @Jim B, If the DHCP server flakes, there's a good chance nobody will notice until the lease start expiring... Or if the power goes out and your DHCP server(s) don't come up for whatever reason...

Comment: @chris s I would think that if you are able to have a server go down in your environment without anyone getting notified, using DHCP on your server is the least of your problems.  I was just being a little nitpicky as the major flaws in this idea overshadow the minute details of why this is a bad idea

Comment: Whoever instituted this policy knows nothing about IT.